# Is it possible to install a sim module on a raspberry pi and a radio transmitter?

Tags: raspberry-pi-desktop, simulink

I was wondering if it is possible to add a sim module and a radio transmitter module to a raspberry pi as i want to be able to, from my computer at home, plug an rc controller into my pc and send a signal straight to my raspberry pi on a drone or an rc buggy and then the raspberry pi ( which can be mounted and powered by the buggy / drone ) can send the signal with the radio transmitter to the rc drone or buggy emulating my proximity to it and theoretically give me unlimited range as long as i have a cellular tower nearby?

Does anyone think it is possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible ... it is being done by many people every day

Comment: SIM yes, radio transmitter (not SIM related) not without considering what radio bands are allowed in your local area. As @jsotola says it's being done every day.

Comment: would radio bands be an issue if it is too far up in the sky for interference.. im planning on only using 2.4ghz so it shouldnt be an issue anyway.